# How to avoid having thousands of files in collectstatic with django packages and/or bower?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using several django packages (rest_framework, ...) and several bower packages (summernote, ...). When doing collectstatic, lots of files get collected, including some which are certainly not needed by the application (examples, ...)

So, I end up syncing around 10000 files to S3 for a very small site, which doesn't make any sense. How to make this whole process a bit more sensible?

I would say the culprit is django's collectstatic, and not the `aws s3 sync` which just does what I tell it: upload everything from collectstatic.

Answer (score 1):

I can share with you our approach: we never put `bower_components` and other such libraries directly in the static directory. We put them somewhere else and then have a `grunt` task that copies only the files we need into the static directory.

A basic setup looks something like:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // Copy only the stuff we need from bower_components
    copy: {
        all: {
            files: [
                // JS
                {
                    expand: true, flatten: true,
                    // You can be more generic with something like "bower_components/**/*.min.js"
                    src: [
                        "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/*.min.js",
                        "bower_components/jquery/*.min.js"
                    ],
                    dest: "static/js/"
                },
                // Same for CSS
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

This approach has its flaws - you now have an extra piece of config to maintain on top of your `bower.json` etc. It will also only help to deal with the files generated by *your* applications.

In addition to this you can add some [`--exclude`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#options) patterns to `aws s3 sync` to filter out the most obvious fluff. Again there is a caveat here that you may end up causing more problems than you solve if you are not careful what you exclude!

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking more or less on a similar approach, but seems quite maintenance intensive. I'll leave it open to see if somebody else provides a better solution.